# Excel: Way to query a range for applicable record based on single queried date using effective date in reference range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working with two Excel worksheets for this task.

Worksheet 1: This worksheet's table tracks the relationship between people during a particular date range. The structure for each record is [Person1, Person2, Begin Date, End Date (null unless applicable)]. Person1 is a project leader and Person2 is an assistant to the project leader. These records are not replaced; a new record is added to the table when a relationship changes.

Worksheet 2: This is a chronological record of projects for Person 1 that references Worksheet 1 to find Person 2 based on the date of the project. The structure is [Person1, ProjectName, ProjectDetail, EffectiveDate, Person2 (a query)]

I would like to use the EffectiveDate on Worksheet 2 to find the applicable Person2 for each record where it falls inside the range stated on Worksheet 1. Worksheet 2 has hundreds of records added on a regular basis. This would allow a formula in the Person2 column to be static and return a value as the records are added to the sheet.

Hopefully this makes sense, thank you in advance for the help!

```
Worksheet 1                         
Person1            Person2         BeginDate EndDate                    
Lara Rios          Sylvia Erickson 6/5/19    3/5/20                 
Ismael Dunn        Tommie Bullock  5/23/19   3/5/20                 
Lorie Ramirez      Mary Webster    3/28/20                      
Georgette Bartlett Jessica Stuart  10/19/19                     
Rashad Hardin      Vincent Hampton 2/10/19   3/5/20                 
Lara Rios          Tommie Bullock  3/5/20                       
Ismael Dunn        Vincent Hampton 3/5/20                       
Rashad Hardin      Sylvia Erickson 3/5/20                       

Worksheet 2         
Person1             ProjectName        ProjectDetail   EffectiveDate  Person2
Lara Rios           Widget City, Inc   Bicycles        7/19/19        [query to find Person2]
Ismael Dunn         Partners, LLC      Storage Space   12/5/19        [query to find Person2]
Lorie Ramirez       Sample Co          Food Prep       3/5/20         [query to find Person2]
Georgette Bartlett  Create New, LP     Table Placement 4/30/20        [query to find Person2]
Rashad Hardin       Precipitation, LLC Rain Barrels    5/1/20         [query to find Person2]
```

As you can see in Worksheet 1, for example, Sylvia worked with Lara for 9 months but now works with Rashad. Her name would be returned on the Widget City project last July, but her name would also be returned on the Precipitation project from the beginning of May. Without using a date in the formula, it will return the wrong result in one of the cells.

Comment: please mock up some data, the minimum necessary to show what you have and what you want to accomplish.  [edit] the post to include the mock up data and expected output.  "A picture is worth 1000 words."

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm quite new to this formatting method, hopefully that makes a bit more sense! Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If one has the Dynamic Array formula `Filter()`:

```
=@FILTER($B$2:$B$9,($A$2:$A$9=F2)*($C$2:$C$9<=I2)*(IF($D$2:$D$9="",TODAY(),$D$2:$D$9)>=I2),"")
```

[image]

---

If not then:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($B$2:$B$9)/(($A$2:$A$9=F2)*($C$2:$C$9<=I2)*(IF($D$2:$D$9="",TODAY(),$D$2:$D$9)>=I2)),1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this incredible response. I think this is the best option. It appears to work well in the example (on my end as well), but I'm having difficulty with it returning anything other than the first person's name in the list in my actual worksheet. I was forgetting initially to mark it as an array with Ctrl+Shift+Enter which was causing it to error with #VALUE! but now seems to just not pull an accurate result. If you have any insight as to what I should check, I truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can try following array formula:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$9,MATCH(1,(A16=$A$2:$A$9)*(D16>=$C$2:$C$9)*(D16<IF($D$2:$D$9="",TODAY(),$D$2:$D$9)),0))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]